# Its been appending empty list while i call it recursively inside a function its should give result of [[2,2,3],7] but it gives me [[],[]]

Tags: python, recursion

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        ans=[]
        l=[]
        def cand(inx ,target,arr,ans, l):
            if inx == len(candidates):
                if target == 0:
                    ans.append(l)
                return
            if arr[inx] <=  target:
                l.append(arr[inx])
                cand(inx,target-arr[inx],arr,ans,l)
                l.pop()
            cand(inx+1,target,arr,ans,l)    
        cand(0,target,candidates,ans,l)
        return ans
```

Comment: What values are you passing to this function? Also, maybe you could explain what this function is trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Because the list in python function is call by reference, you should copy the result when append in answer. **ans.append(l[:])**

```py
from typing import List

class Solution:

    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        ans = []
        l = []

        def cand(inx, target, arr, ans, l):
            if inx == len(candidates):
                if target == 0:
                    # here is difference
                    ans.append(l[:])
                return
            if arr[inx] <= target:
                l.append(arr[inx])
                cand(inx, target - arr[inx], arr, ans, l)
                l.pop()
            cand(inx + 1, target, arr, ans, l)

        cand(0, target, candidates, ans, l)
        return ans

candidates = [2, 3, 6, 7]
target = 7
s = Solution()
ans = s.combinationSum(candidates, target)
print(ans)
```

result:

```py
[[2, 2, 3], [7]]
```